# Recursive C++ Combinatorics: Not sure how to get the results in order

Tags: c++, recursion, combinatorics

I have a function to print all of the ternary string combinations from length 0 to length n:

```
void TerString(int len,string input){
    printf("\n%s",input.c_str());
    if (input.length()<len){
        TerString(len,input+"0");
        TerString(len,input+"1");
        TerString(len,input+"2");
        return;
    }
    else
    return;
}
```

However, I'm not entirely sure how to go about getting these in a logical order. For example, the results come out like this when I invoke TerString(3,""):
0,00,000,001,002,01,010,011,012,02,020,021,022,1,10,100,101,102,11,110,111,112,12,120,121,122,2,20,200,201,202,21,210,211,212,22,220,221,222

I would like them to come out in lexicographical order like this:
0,1,2,00,01,02,10,11,12,20,21,22,...etc...

Without loading them into an array/list and using a sort algorithm, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that all the strings of the same length are already in the right order.  And the example you gave isn't *lexicographical* order at all, it's ordered by length.  *Lexicographical* order (i.e. dictionary sort) is what you're already seeing.

To get results sorted by length, iterate by length first, and generate only strings of the desired length:

```
void TerStringHelper( size_t pos, string& input )
{
    if (pos >= input.size())
        cout << input << endl;
    else
        for( input[pos] = '0'; input[pos] < '3'; input[pos]++ )
            TerStringHelper(pos+1, input);
}

void TerString( size_t maxlen )
{
     string input = "-";
     while (input.size() <= maxlen) {
         TerStringHelper(0, input);
         input += '-';
     }
}
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/P9u6R)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
void TerString(int len, string prefix){
    printf("\n%s%s", input.c_str(), "0");
    printf("\n%s%s", input.c_str(), "1");
    printf("\n%s%s", input.c_str(), "2");
    if (--len > 0) {
        TerString(len, input+"0");
        TerString(len, input+"1");
        TerString(len, input+"2");
    }
}
```

Comment: it will print: 0,1,2,00,01,02,001,002,003,... won't it?

Comment: also you are both increasing the string`s size and decreasing len, which will cause only half of requested length.

Comment: @amit: No, because he compares `len` to zero, it's not closing in from both ends.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: you are right about the len, still the print will be off order